# Prevent workbook deactivate during ribbon invalidate in Excel

Tags: excel, ribbon

Ribbon calls macros that are available to a specific workbook.
If you activate a different workbook while ribbon invalidate takes place, these macros are no more available so i get the expected "can not find macros" errors.

Is there anyway to resolve this?
Maybe prevent user to activate another workbook while ribbon invalidates?
Is there any way to cancel deactivate of a workbook?